# Proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ - logic question

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Prove $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. (Proof by contradiction).

Let $\sqrt{3}$ be a rational number in simplest form $\frac pq$.

So squaring both sides of $\sqrt{3}=\frac pq$ we get $3=(\frac {p}{q})^2$ which translates to $3=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.

Multiply both sides of the equation by $q^2$ yields $3q^2=p^2$. Now $p^2$ is taken to be divisible by 3 and thus an odd number, $p$ is also odd because any odd number squared is also odd.

So let $p=3s$ where s is an integer. Then $3q^2=(3s)^2 = 3q^2=9s^2$. Dividing both sides of the equation by 3 leaves us with $q^2=3s^2$.

Here is is taken that $q^2$ is divisible by 3 and is odd and so is $q$.

Therefore both $q \text{ and}\; p$ have a common factor of being odd and divisible by 3, proving that the $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Are there any gaps that I could improve on?

Comment: The part "$p^2$ is divisible by $3$ and therefore an odd number" is not true, $6^2$ is divisible by $3$ but not odd.

Comment: You might also want to simplify matters by assuming, for the sake of contradiction, that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{3} = \frac{p}{q} \text{ and}\; gcd(p,q) = 1.$

Comment: @AndréNicolas - so does $6$ itself :)

Comment: True! But I wanted to quote the OP exactly.

Comment: @Jake +1 for showing your work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Critiques on proof showing $\sqrt{12}$ is irrational.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305559/critiques-on-proof-showing-sqrt12-is-irrational)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Surely critiques are localised to the specific question, no? Jake cannot gain a critique of his proof by looking at critiques of user21154's proof...

Comment: @user1729 their proof nearly looks quiet the same. I voted to close mainly to shorten the unanswered questions. As it seems here is no work left to done I thought linking to a pretty similiar question

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Why not upvote an answer then?! This is a perfectly good question which does not deserve to be closed! (Although I do understand your point, as it is an old question. But still, a simple upvote is much neater and more elegant!)

Comment: @user1729 closing a question doesn't mean that it is bad. I think those check my prof questions are most times to localized. I did not found any answer extremely nice and wanted to clean up more so  I need to save some upvotes :)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Maybe I am a bit loose with my upvotes... but anyway, I do agree that "check my proof" questions are too localised, but then of course we could close it as such, no? (And perhaps say that this question is similar to the linked one, in that they make the same error.)

Comment: @User1729 yeah maybe that have been the better way to do so

Answer (score 2):

"Now $p^2$ is taken to be divisible by 3 and thus an odd number, $p$ is also odd because any odd number squared is also odd." That's a non-sequitur. The fact that any odd number squared is odd doesn't rule out other numbers being odd.

"So let $p=3s$ where s is an integer." That's illegitimate. $p$'s being odd doesn't make it multiple of 3.

So you need to repair the argument from $p^2$ being taken to be divisible by 3 to $p$ being of the form $p=3s$.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what to do to repair the argument, could you give me a nudge in the right direction?

Could I say the LHS is odd and so is the RHS, so p^2 must be odd. Then go on to replace p with 3s?

Comment: @Jake To repair your proof you need to supply a *valid* proof that $\rm\:3\mid n^2\:\Rightarrow\:3\mid n\ \ $ You seem to be mimicking one well-known proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2},\:$ which uses the parity of $\rm\,n.\:$ That idea can be generalized to give an analogous proof here by working mod $3$ instead of mod $2.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm doing an exercise that follows the proof of the irrationality of sqroot{2}. So I'm trying to use that as a base to start from. From the step p^2=3q^2, that p^2 is a multiple of 3, and so is p? Now setting p=3s. Would this satisfy the proof?

Is the difference between the sqroot[2] and sqroot[3] reasoning be that in the case of 3 it won't necessarily be odd but rather a multiple of 3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Firstly, the analogoues of *even* number when proving $\sqrt2$ is irrational, is not the **odd** numbers for $\sqrt3$, but the numbers '*divisible by $3$*' (and these are not necessarily odd, for example $12$).

Secondly, it is not finished yet. You have to divide the $3$'s for an *infinite time*, contradicting the fundamental thm of number theory, or, the easiest, is that $p$ and $q$ are assumed to be relatively primes (else $\displaystyle\frac pq$ would be simplifiable).

Answer (score 1):

1) I would change the first "Let" to be "assume by negation"

2) 2) $p^{2}$ is not taken to be divisible by $3$, we concluded this

3) "and thus an odd number" - this is wrong since, for example, $3\mid6$
but $6$ is not odd

Answer (score 0):

You must assume that $gcd(p,q)=1$, then you get contradiction in the last part of your proof.

Comment: I guess this is what the OP meant by "in simplest form"

Comment: When I do these proofs, rather than assuming coprimality, I prefer to assume that $p$ and $q$ are finite integers and point out that you can keep factoring out a 3 indefinetely. Thus contradiction.

Comment: @Belgi: Yes: *in simplest form* is a fairly common English synonym of *in lowest terms* and *reduced*, especially in grade school.