# If $c^2 = 12$, then show that $c$ is an irrational number.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Show that, if $x$ satisfies $x^2 = 3$, then $c := 2x$ satisfies $c^2 = 12$. Using this fact, show that $c$ is an irrational number.

Comment: Have you already proved that $x$ is irrational?

Comment: Have not proved that x is irrational yet.

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to analysis. I will look at the question tagged above.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x^2 &= 3 \\
\left( \frac c2 \right) ^2 &= 3 \\
\frac{c^2}{4} &= 3 \\
c^2 &= 12 \\
c &= \pm2\sqrt 3 \\
\end{align}$$

Since $\sqrt 3$ is irrational, so is $\pm2\sqrt 3$ (this has [already been proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305562/347062) on MSE).

Comment: Maybe add the fact that any non-zero rational number times an irrational number is irrational as well, which isn't hard to prove either.,

Comment: @WaveX I stated that in there, but I figured the OP could easily Google the proof.

Comment: I reckon that $c=2\sqrt3$ (or $-2\sqrt3$).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah duh thank you