# Show that there is no rational number $r=m/n$ such that $r^3=3$

Tags: analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

How do I solve this by prime factorization?

I came across  a similar problem on MSE just recently, but I can't find it and I thoroughly searched for it. If anyone can find it, please post it in the comment so that I can delete this question.

---

**Update**: I don't know if it makes a difference, but please note that this is *cubed* root

---

Comment: It is the question [Proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ - logic question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/234983/752).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Does it make a difference that this is *cubed root*?

Comment: Yeah,I missed that. It probably doesn't make much difference, but that particular question is very specific to $\sqrt{3}$, unfortunately - it doesn't include the standard "prime" proof which would work for $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: Oops, I mis-read the cubed root, too, when voting duplicate.

Comment: @AlanH: The exact same method as used in the $\sqrt{3}$ question will solve your problem here - in fact it shows that $3^{1/n}$ is always irrational as long as $b\geq 2$ is an integer.

Comment: I think this fits better as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91538/prove-21-3-is-irrational/91757#91757  In any case, it is a duplicate.

Comment: @EricNaslund Do you mean as long as $n\geq 2$ is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose so then

$$m^3 = 3n^3$$

but if that's true then the prime 3 divides $m$, so write $m = 3m'$ and we have

$$9m'^3 = n^3$$

and so n is a multiple of 3 too, put $n = 3n'$ and we have

$$m'^3 = 3n'^3$$

but this $(m',n')$ pair is smaller than $(m,n)$ so we have *infinite descent* proving there is no solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=\frac{m}{n}$ s.t $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $r^3=1$ then we have $m^3=3n^3$ and since $\gcd(m^3,n^3)=1$ then $3$ divides $m^3$ and since $3$ is prime number then $3$ divides $m$ so $m=3m'$ and then we have $9m'^3=n^3$ and $\gcd(m',n)=1$ so $3$ divides $n$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is such a rational number. We may assume that $r = \frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Whence, $m^3 = 3n^3$ so that $3 \mid m$. Set $m = 3m_1$, the previous equality implies $9m_1^3 = n$ so that $3 \mid n$, a contradiction to the assumption that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.